# Manual Solutions for Abstract Algebra book

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, book-recommendation

Does somebody know about the existence of the manual solution for Abstract Algebra by Fraleigh or by Herstein?
Where can I find it?

I don't have money so I can't buy it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjntbXahdPTAhUIpo8KHSEHB5YQFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffaculty.ksu.edu.sa%2Ffawaz%2F343%2Fothers%2Fgrouptheory1.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFTF9kutDvciAGE25ExZKr_ibMq3g&sig2=Ov86l5fLSys3t_t_msMW-A) has a few (Herstein)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The solution manual for Fraleigh's Abstract algebra is available and you can download/find it from $\textbf{Bookzz.org}$.

For Herstein's Topics in Algebra, there is no complete manual solution. but solution for some chapters are available

Comment: You're Welcome!!